# Same message in sender and receiver chat in pusher.js php

Tags: javascript, php, real-time, pusher, pusher-js

I am new to **PusherJS** and developing a real-time chat app using PHP. Everything working fine but when I press enter to send message, it append it in sender's box and into receiver's box also. How I can differentiate it on the basis of **session** or **user_id**. See there are same message is sender and receiver's box:
[image]

**Real-Time.php:**

```
$options = array(
    'cluster' => 'ap2',
    'useTLS' => true
);
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    'c575a7********edb87d',
    '8fee27********57fdd2',
    '7***6*',
    $options
);
$pusher->trigger('channel', 'event', $data);
```

**The .js file:**

```
var pusher = new Pusher('c575a76********db87d', {
    cluster: 'ap2',
    forceTLS: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel');
channel.bind('event', function(data) {

    var msg_template = ``; //<-- Just removed template it's simple HTML

    $("ul#messages").append(msg_template);
});
```

Comment: FYI pusher now offers a dedicated chat product: https://pusher.com/chatkit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the message sender from receiving the broadcasted message. How to do so is documented at on the [Pusher website](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/excluding-event-recipients).

First, you need to store the SocketID when connecting to Channels:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY');
var socketId = null;
pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
  socketId = pusher.connection.socket_id;
});
```

Once this has been found, you can use it in the event sent to the server:

```
data: {
      id: 'some_id',
      updated_value: 'some_value',
      socket_id: socketId // pass socket_id parameter to be used by server
    }
```

This will then prevent the client with that socketId from receiving the message.